# InDesign: Why are my text frames shifting down slightly when I copy them from a master page and paste in place to other masters and pages?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, master-page

I am creating a number of business card variations in InDesign CC 2014 on a Windows 7 Professional 64-bit system. I am attempting to copy text frames from one master and paste them in place on another master.

However, when I paste in place my text frames shift down slightly. It also appears that sometime different text frames shift while others stay in the proper place. Additionally, when I override master page items to edit the text it also shifts.

I've done my best to check all aspects of text formatting to make sure I'm not accidently adding whitespace or changing line height before a chunk of text.

Has anyone else encountered this issue, and if so, do you know a solution?

Comment: perhaps a caching issue? the Adobe apps keep a cach of your on-screen view. Try zooming out, then zooming back in.

Comment: Do you have any kind of text wrap on anything? Or Snap to guide/point/etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I think your file is `aligned to baseline grid`.

This is actually the best way to work on print (typography speaking)

In order to cancel it just select the text box go to the paragraph window and on the bottom of the window you'll see the align/not align to baseline grid buttons.

In order to try to work with it go toy your artboard, right click and press "show baseline grid"